# Unable to select and display in ngbdatepicker for 4000 years

Tags: angular, maxdate, ngb-datepicker

I am using ngbDatepicker in my angular application. I have a couple of requirements.

1. In the year select box, I need to limit the user to select a year up to 4000. At the same time, I need infinite navigation behavior which is the default in ngbdatepicker. I tried maxDate property, but it is detaching the infinite navigation behavior and it displays the years all at once.
2. I need to display [-10, +20] years from the currently visible month in ngbdatepicker year select box. The default behavior is [-10, +10] years from currently visible month.

This is what I have tried

```
 <input class="form-control" 
  type="text" 
  formControlName="dateofJoining" 
  placeholder="Date of Joining" 
  id="inputDateOfJoining" 
  name="doJ" 
  ngbDatepicker 
  #d="ngbDatepicker" 
  [minDate]="{year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}" 
  [maxDate]="{year: 4000, month: 1, day: 1}" />
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi Kurt. This is what i have tried.

<input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="dateofJoining" placeholder="Date of Joining"
                     id="inputDateOfJoining" name="doJ" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
                     [minDate]="{year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}"
  [maxDate]="{year: 4000, month: 1, day: 1}">